# Google Sitemap Date Format

Tags: php, sitemap, date-format

I need date format for sitemaps in php.

How can i do that ?

Is this output right ?

```
<lastmod>2012-08-02EEST18:01:18+03:00</lastmod>
```

Comment: do you mean sitemaps grabbed by bots ?

Answer (score 46):

If you have the timestamp you can format the date correctly like this:

```
<lastmod><?php echo date('c', $timestamp); ?></lastmod>
```

Time stamp could be `time()` (for current time) or some other method of fetching a unix tiemstamp like `strtotime()`

Comment: i'm recieving lastmod data from database. and it's datetime format. I'm using strtotime to convert. if type is correct for google it works. Thank you.

Comment: and if you have date string like `2023-12-14 20:38` you can use `date('c', strtotime($dateTime));`

Answer (score 28):

To format the current timestamp in W3C Datetime encoding (as used in sitemap.xml files) use the following parameters.

```
echo date('Y-m-dTH:i:sP', time());
```

As of PHP5 you can also use the c format character to print the exact same string.

```
echo date('c',time());
```

These would both print out the following:

```
2009-04-03T11:49:00+01:00
```

[SOURCE](http://www.hashbangcode.com/blog/xml-sitemap-date-format-php-359.html)

Comment: The date string you give is the case of @user1329212 's problem.  I have posted the correct string as an answer.

Comment: @AdamJones and the answer from @NXT are correct: if you're using the date format string `Y-m-dTH:i:sP`, you need to escape the T i.e. `Y-m-d\TH:i:sP`. However using the PHP5 option date('c',time()) works perfectly.

Comment: @FluffyKitten Works for me i have the problem with the "T" char the problem fix with the escape ! Thanks !

Answer (score 23):

To convert from a MySQL's datetime format to the one needed for **lastmod** in sitemaps, just use the PHP code below.

```
$lastmod = '2012-11-28 10:53:17'; //MySQL datetime format

$datetime = new DateTime($lastmod);
$result = $datetime->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:sP');

echo $result; //2012-11-28T10:53:17+01:00
```

Comment: Could use shorter format `$result = $datetime->format('c');`.
`

Answer (score 12):

[According to Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183668?hl=en&ref_topic=6080646&rd=1), he  value is an optional field that, if provided, must be formatted as

```
YYYY-MM-DDThh:mmTZD
```

The default export of an SQL datetime is [dependent on the language setting for your server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14769547/sql-server-datetime-format), and may include spaces and characterized TZD such as:

```
2014-09-19 10:33:05 UTC
```

[The W3 specify](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) that TZD can be formatted in any of three options

TZD  = time zone designator (Z or +hh:mm or -hh:mm)

Any spaces from your default formatting must be stripped; the character 'T' must be inserted before time, and the TZD must match one of the supported types.

Therefore to format the current timestamp, use the following parameters.

```
echo date('Y-m-dTH:i:sP', time());
```

As of PHP5 you can also use the c format character to print the exact same string.

```
echo date('c',time());
```

Answer (score 6):

I know the question was about PHP, but I found this page googling for Node/JavaScript. So the closest equivalent is `Date.toISOString()`:

```
var d = new Date();
d.toISOString(); // "2017-04-19T07:23:16.040Z"
```

Comment: If there isn't an question & answer already on SO for a javascript version, you should consider adding this as a new question for other users who are also searching for this too! See [Answering your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 4):

Your getting this output because you used the old recommended timestamp string of

```
Y-m-dTH:i:sP.
```

However, what you need is

```
Y-m-d\TH:i:sP
```

This single back slash will make the difference.   At some point a capital T became a special character in PHP signifying timecode, so if you don't escape the T you will get exactly what your reporting.

Answer (score 2):

[You have a lot of formats to choose from](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime). Using the `c` parameter with the [`date()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function will get the recommended format for you.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there are 2 approaches to this.

**The first** approach is to set a valid date for XML sitemap which includes the "C" char which gave the value: *(2019-06-03T17:30:21-05:00)*. **[Test it here](https://tools.seochat.com/tools/site-validator/)**

`<lastmod>'.date('c', strtotime($row['date'])).'</lastmod>`

**The 2nd** approach is to set a valid date for RSS sitemap which includes the "r" char which gave the value: *(2019-03-07T17:55:44+00:00)*.

`<pubDate>'.date('r', strtotime($row['date'])).'</pubDate>`

Hope this helps you. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

delete "EES"
Mine is like this 2013-12-26T19:00:00-05:00
and it works
http://www.industry-automation-parts.com/1_e_0_sitemap.xml

Answer (score 0):

with moment.js;

```
moment().format('YYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ')
```

Comment: Can you explain that further? I don't think that `moment.js` is available for PHP after all