# SQL SERVER DATETIME FORMAT

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

Studying SQL Server there is something I am not sure of:

A `datetime` field with the value:
`2012-02-26 09:34:00.000`

If I select out of the table using:

```
CAST(dob2 AS VARCHAR(12) ) AS d1
```

It formats it as:
`Feb 26 2012`

What I am unsure of his how or why SQL Server formats DateTime like that. If you use `datetime2` it does not - anyone know why?

Comment: You can use **[`CONVERT()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)** to choose how a date(time) is formatted.

Comment: Look at the remarks to 
Date and Time Styles here: [CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default date format depends on the language setting for the database server.  You can also [change it per session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174398.aspx), like:

```
set language french
select cast(getdate() as varchar(50))
-->
févr 8 2013 9:45AM
```

Comment: The date format is not only dependent on the language setting, it can be overridden by `SET DATEFORMAT`. See the "Remarks" section here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx

Answer (score 7):

try this:

```
select convert(varchar, dob2, 101)
select convert(varchar, dob2, 102)
select convert(varchar, dob2, 103)
select convert(varchar, dob2, 104)
select convert(varchar, dob2, 105)
select convert(varchar, dob2, 106)
select convert(varchar, dob2, 107)
select convert(varchar, dob2, 108)
select convert(varchar, dob2, 109)
select convert(varchar, dob2, 110)
select convert(varchar, dob2, 111)
select convert(varchar, dob2, 112)
select convert(varchar, dob2, 113)
```

refernces: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: I was demonstrating the different format... the references should explain the theory.

Answer (score 5):

[Compatibility Supports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) Says that
Under compatibility level 110, the default style for **`CAST and CONVERT`** operations on `time` and **`datetime2`** data types is always 121. If your query relies on the old behavior, use a compatibility level less than 110, or explicitly specify the 0 style in the affected query.

That means *by default* `datetime2` *is* `CAST as varchar` *to* `121 format`. For ex; `col1` *and* `col2` formats (below) are same (other than the 0s at the end)

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 121) col1,
       CAST(convert(datetime2,GETDATE()) as varchar) col2,
       CAST(GETDATE() as varchar) col3
```

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/8597)

```
--Results
COL1                    | COL2                          | COL3
2013-02-08 09:53:56.223 | 2013-02-08 09:53:56.2230000   | Feb 8 2013 9:53AM
```

FYI, if you use `CONVERT` instead of `CAST` you can use a third parameter to specify certain formats as listed here on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

In MS SQL Server you can do:

```
SET DATEFORMAT ymd
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
case when isdate(inputdate) = 1 
then convert(datetime, cast(inputdate,datetime2), 103)
else
case when isdate(inputdate) = 0 
then convert(datetime, cast(inputdate,datetime2), 103)
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is my favorite use of 112 and 114**

```
select (convert(varchar, getdate(), 112)+ replace(convert(varchar, getdate(), 114),':','')) as 'Getdate() 

112 + 114 or YYYYMMDDHHMMSSMSS'
```

**Result:**

> Getdate() 112 + 114 or YYYYMMDDHHMMSSMSS

**20171016083349100**

Answer (score 0):

to change the date format by using sql syntax you should use this query

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`<columnName>`, '%d/%m/%Y') FROM schemaname.tablename;
```

ex:-

for suppose i have a schema named as bugloo and the table name is `tbl_company`
and in this `tbl_company` i have a column all are in the date format `%yy/%mm/%dd` and column name is `createdDate` and the query should like this

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`createdDate`, '%d/%m/%Y') FROM bugloo.tbl_company;
```

after running this query my output date would be converted to `%dd/%mm/%yyyy`