# Sql Server Date Time Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to retrieve my date in a 110 format (here you can refer the format *"http://www.sql-server-helper.com/sql-server-2008/sql-server-2008-date-format.aspx"*)
But my system is returning date in 109 format).
below is my code

```
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME
SET @startDate = SYSDATETIME()
PRINT(@startDate)
```

please help since im doing some process on getting the date in 110 format.

Comment: Where did you try to set that format? Probably it is returning just a 'date' and it's up to the client to display that in some format. (and `print` doesn't return anything).

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL SERVER DATETIME FORMAT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14769547/sql-server-datetime-format)

Comment: thanks guys it was coming due to datetime datatype i have replaced it with date and hence i m getting the data as i want in that format

Answer (score 2):

Just convert to varchar...

```
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME
SET @startDate = GetDate()
PRINT(Convert(varchar(max),@startDate,110))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME = SYSDATETIME() 
PRINT(Convert(varchar(10), @startDate, 110))
```

Comment: Please don't sign your posts.