# date , time date format

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

NEED an output like

```
11/23/15 05:14:05 PM
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL SERVER DATETIME FORMAT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14769547/sql-server-datetime-format)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), SYSDATETIME(), 22)
```

there are many available formats on the net.. try some googling.

below are sample link:

http://www.sql-server-helper.com/sql-server-2008/sql-server-2008-date-format.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Or you can try this:

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'MM/dd/yy hh:mm:ss tt', 'en-US')
```

You can customize the date time format as you like.

Comment: Works only in SQL Server **2012** and newer since `FORMAT` was introduced in the 2012 version - isn't available in earlier versions (and the OP says he's using SQL Server **2008 R2** which doesn't have `FORMAT` yet)

Comment: `CONVERT` function will do on all earlier versions , but i also used that `FORMAT` function because i am using 2012 :)