# Sitemap lastmod date in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, xml, sitemap

I need to the date format that is shown in `<lastmod></lastmod>` tags in sitemap.xml. How can I achieve that?

Output like:

```
<lastmod>2016-01-21EEST18:01:18+03:00</lastmod>
```

Where 'EEST' is probably timezone offset.

I have seen this question and the answers in php:

[Google Sitemap Date Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11780404/google-sitemap-date-format/11780462)

but don't know how to achieve it in Javascript,

Thanks.

EDIT: the question is not duplicate, since I need the correct time format in JavaScript for this.

Comment: No it is not a duplicate, as I need to know the timeformat for this..

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The lastmod tag uses `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mmTZD` format, where TZD is the time zone offset. The [W3 date and time format](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) gives you 3 options for how to do the TZD: (Z or +hh:mm or -hh:mm)

This means that in javascript you can just use

```
const date = new Date().toISOString();
```

and it'll look like `2017-11-15T11:18:17.266Z`, which is correct for a sitemap lastmod.

Comment: How can we show in +hh:mm or -hh:mm instead of Z? Official documentation uses +hh:mm format. https://www.google.com/sitemaps/protocol.html